# Visual Web Developer 2010 - SQLDataSource - No MySQL option

Tags: mysql, odbc, visual-web-developer

Is there no way to select to use a MySQl database in Visual Web Developer when using SQLdataSource?

I am using MySQL 5.5 and visual Web Developer express 2010 sp1.

It appears from the book I am reading that this was available in 2005 but has it been removed in 2010, I cannot see an option to connect.

Answer (score 1):

In SelectCommand you must remove the  [ ]  that does not use MySQL, but the Insert, Update, Delete Automatic unable to work, just the same Select. If anyone knows to use the Insert, update, delete automatic put here for us.